# Picture posting NOT working with facebook Graph API anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Picture posting NOT working with Facebook Graph API

The message is posted but the picture is NOT.

I am using the Graph API to post to the wall on Facebook.

My code was working fine posting the picture but is NOT posting picture anymore!

Here are the CURL parameters:

I am posting to URL: https://graph.facebook.com/ID/feed

and the POST parameters are:

```
access_token=TheToken&message=My+Message&picture=ImgUrl
```

where:
access_token is a valid access token
message is the message to display on the wall
picture is the image associated with the message to display on the wall

```
The ID is valid and access_token is valid.
```

Any help is appreciated, Facebook seems to be notorious in changing their API without informing interfacing sites!

Comment: I'm creating feed posts with the Graph API and I'm still able to post images? Perhaps double-check your parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the LINK parameter instead of the PICTURE parameter and all seems to be working now.  Facebook changed something in regards to the PICTURE parameter where it stopped working.  I did NOT change any code on my system and it just stopped working.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when posting using the graph api via PHP. Dont know what the cause what, but my image URLs contained a - sign (http://the.url/to/the-image.jpg). 
After renaming the images, everything worked as expected.

What is your image url?

Comment: thanks,my problem was _ sign in url.your answer solved my problem.Upvote.

Comment: Adding a comment as this is the top answer. The problem could also be that you are specifying a https url to the picture, but are using a self signed certificate. Facebook seems to reject self signed certificates when accessing images.

Comment: Thanks mate. Such a shame nowhere on facebook manual you can find about this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Ken, but what if you want link= to point to something else? this works:

```
curl -F \
     "picture=http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/gif/moons/m146.gif" \
     -F "message=you're looking great tonight!" \
     -F "name=Current Moon Phase" \
     -F "link=http://www.calculatorcat.com/moon_phases/phasenow.php" -F caption="How the moon appears tonight" \
     -F "access_token=111111111111111|2222222222222222222222222|33333333333333333333456n" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com/215958041750734/feed"
```

you can see result at: https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Moon/215958041750734

Answer (score 2):

works for me using source parameter:

```php
$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?"
          . "source=" . urlencode($_POST["picture"])
          . "&link=" . urlencode($_POST["link"])
          . "&message=" . urlencode($_POST['message'])
          . "&method=POST"
          . "&access_token=" .$access_token;
$response=file_get_contents($graph_url);
$json=json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting picture works for me but somehow including a source (swf) causes the picture to not display anymore. This used to work until last week.

Answer (score 0):

*Wait for it*

I noticed that it takes more time for Facebook to process the picture (up to 15 minutes) than to post the link on the timeline (instant).