# Facebook Feed dialog image URL length

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

Code:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: "Test Name",
        link: "http://www.facebook.com",
        picture: "https://www.rwe-smarthome.de/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/RWEEffizienz-SmartHome-Site/RWEEffizienz-SmartHome/de_DE/Energiesparpaket%20plus/Energiesparpaket-Plus_170px_198px.png",
        caption: '',
        description: "Some description goes here",
    },function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            //alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
            //alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    });
```

Above code showing a facebook feed dialog, but without image. I think problem is with the length of the picture argument. Replacing the picture URL with any other short image URL will do the work. I cant't change the picture URL, cause its coming from a webservice. Is there any length constraint for facebook feed dialog for the Picture url?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502883/picture-posting-not-working-with-facebook-graph-api-anymore/5572622#5572622

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parameter to the non-HTTPS version of the image.

Comment: Did you try with that very URL in your example? Because the HTTP version of that immediately redirects to HTTPS again …

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the picture URL, cause its coming from a third party web-service.

Comment: Short URL with https working fine. Try "https://timg.tellja.de/img/kdg/image-3_frau_kip.jpg"