# posting to page stream - api returns id but post does not appear in stream

Tags: facebook, api, post, stream

I'm running a little PHP-Application where some users connect to Facebook and post to their page feeds, using the graph api.
It runs fine, no problems, until today when a user told me his posting didn't appear on his page. I checked my database and logfiles, there were no exceptions from the facebook api, it returned an id for the new post.
I tried posting the exact same posting with the same image-file attached to my own page and everything worked just as expected.

Here is the PHP-Code performing the API-Call:

```
$fb = new facebook(array('appId'=>FB_APP_ID, 'secret'=>FB_APP_SECRET, 'cookie'=>true));
try {
  if(!empty($post->file)) {
    $do = "photos";
    $request['fileUpload'] = true;
    $request['source']     = "@".realpath("data/srmfiles/{$userIdentity->id}/{$post->file}");
    $fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);
  }
  $postToId = ($do=="photos" && $post->facebook_page->facebookFotoAlbumId)
          ? $post->facebook_page->facebookFotoAlbumId 
          : $post->facebook_page->facebookId;
  $fb->setAccessToken($post->facebook_page->accessToken);
  $response             = $fb->api("/{$postToId}/{$do}","POST",$request);
  $post->wasSuccessfull = 1;
  $post->facebook_id    = $response['id'];
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e){
  $post->failCount++;
  if($post->failCount>=3) {
    $post->wasSuccessfull = -1;
  }
  $handle = fopen("srm-errors-".date("Ymd").".txt","a");
  fwrite($handle,date("H:i:s")." - ".$e->getMessage()."\n");
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem, that Facebook API does not thow an Exception, returns an ID for the new Post, but the Post does not appear on the Page and also can't be viewed directly through the ID?

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't a permission problem? sometimes some applications changes it's permissions during the time when users already have the application installed and the new permissions is never accepted by the user

Comment: The permissions for the app did not change since the specified user signed up. He might have manually withdrawn a permission afterwards (i don't think so, but will ask), but in that case, shouldn't the Facebook API throw an Exception when trying to post?

Comment: It should, but i'm suspecting that it has to be a permission issue. Some permission/s or value (access-token, etc.) must have been changed/manipulated for that particular user. Do you have any more reported cases of that kind?

Comment: No, it is the only one, for all other users it still works fine. I tested sending a post with a wrong access-token, in that case Facebook definitely throws an exception. And i myself just withdrew the post-permission for the app and afterwards tried sending a post, and facebook api threw an exception as expected.  :/

Comment: Ok, you seem to be right! I tried another Posting to an Album with an Image attached, and in that case facebook api does not throw an exception and returns an id for the new post, but the foto is not posted on facebook. So it seems to be an issue with posting fotos to an album, in that case there's no exception if the permission was withdrawn.

Comment: You're saying "I tried posting the exact same posting with the same image-file attached to my own page and everything worked just as expected". What was the URL of that image-file? in many cases where posting URL's with Facebook graph API in PHP, the post doesn't appear because of bad characters like '-' or '_' in the URL. [Like this earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502883/picture-posting-not-working-with-facebook-graph-api-anymore)

Comment: No, URL and Filename were identical. Point is, if the App hasn't the permission to post in my name the API does throw an Exception when I try to post to the id of a page. But an image is postet to an album-id, not to the page-id, and in that case the api does not throw an exception, but returns success with an id for the post, without the post being actually published.