# FB Graph API picture for feed in sandbox mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm a newbie in facebook developer. I just found Graph API for feed without dialog. I tested it on Facebook Sandbox Mode. I used php curl with graph api like this.

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id/feed";
$params = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => "Hello $user->first_name $user->last_name",
    'name' => "Test Name",
    'caption' => "Test Caption",
    'link' => $canvas_page,
    'picture' => $canvas_url."/images/feed3.gif",
    'description' => "Test Descriptionh"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Everything is OK but I cannot see a picture.

http://www.nakamole.com/didnotshowPicture.png

Picture size is 300 x 300 pixel.  Picture url is valid and can show on browser. I saw html source code in browser. I found that url.

```
<img class="_42xb img" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y4/r/-PAXP-deijE.gif" alt="" height="116" width="116" style="background-image: url(http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDUH3LyTZHwrz8d&amp;w=116&amp;h=116&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.100%2Fsimpleid%2Fimages%2Fm146.gif&amp;cfs=1);" />
```

I have seen [Picture posting NOT working with facebook Graph API anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502883/picture-posting-not-working-with-facebook-graph-api-anymore) and tried, picture did not show.

My question is "A picture should be shown in sandbox mode or not? If should be, what's wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem (after try and try and try). The point is ip address. It is an internal  server ip address. Facebook Server cannot find my picture. After changed to real ip and waited for 15 minutes, I get post thumbnail on my test.